# In C++ is it possible to write a lambda that is a condition i.e. just a condition that evaluates to true or false

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, lambda, closures

Example (contrived):

I've written a method that takes can take a "filter" expression, and returns the number of matching items:

```
int getCount(std::function<bool(int, int)> filter)
{
    // Iterate pairs of numbers p,q
    // Count number of pairs where filter(p, q) is true
    // Return count
}
```

I know I can invoke this as follows:

```
getCount([](int x, int y) { return x > y; });
```

But, since the intention is to write a filter "condition" or "expression" i.e. something very declarative and not imperative, I would ideally like to exclude the "return" statement.

Something along the lines of:

```
getCount([](int x, int y) { x > y; });
```

or

```
getCount([](int x, int y) { x > y });
```

Obviously the above aren't possible, but is there anything in for example std or boost that would allow me to achieve this intention?

Basically the user of the getCount method needs to be able to provide a filter condition only, without having to say "return" as an imperative statement.

Comment: You can't return something without `return`.

Comment: @NathanOliver I slightly updated my question. To be more clear, if I have a statement "int a = b + c;" the phrase "b + c" actually returns the value of b + c, but we don't have to say "return". I want to simply say "int a = myfunc"; where somewhere else I say myfunc is "b + c" without having to say "return".

Comment: We don't have to say `return` there because we aren't in a function.  Abstractly `int a = b + c;` calls the `operator+` for `int` it doe the addition and then returns a value, that value is then assigned to `a`.  That `operator+` is still doing a `return`.  Like I said, you can't return a value from a function without using `return`.

Comment: What is the problem with `return`? To me, `[](int x, int y) { return x > y; }` is much more clear than `[](int x, int y) { x > y; }`

Comment: To me, it makes much more sense to use basic stl functions, since they are more flexible and are easily understood by all. like `size_t count = std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0, [=THRESHOLD](size_t n, int x)  { return n + (x > THRESHOLD); });`

Comment: @llonesmiz yeah, I'd make that an answer (perhaps notably, ternary operator isn't supported either because it can't be overloaded)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Boost.Phoenix](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_0/libs/phoenix/doc/html/index.html) for this:

```
using namespace boost::phoenix::placeholders;
getCount(_1 > _2);
```

`_1` and `_2` are [argument placeholders](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_0/libs/phoenix/doc/html/phoenix/modules/core/arguments.html) and the whole relational expression forms a function object that returns the result of comparison.